# Meaning of cannibalized

Tags: meaning

> XP was deemed a tad cultish by some, but it grew out of two decades of object-oriented practice at the highest level and its principles were widely **cannibalized**. In particular, code revision, known as refactoring, was taken up as a powerful adjunct to patterns.

Comment: I have to say, that example strikes me as a poor use of the word "cannibalized".  @MrWonderful's right about the meaning, but usually when one says of a machine that it's "cannibalized for parts" it implies that the thing being cannibalized was _destroyed_, being _utterly consumed_.  Hence the metaphor to _eating people_, rather than an allusion to learning from edifying examples.  Now, maybe the author of that paragraph has strong, hurt feelings about the effect on XP by other methodologies adopting XP practices piecemeal (heaven knows, some do), but that seems not all that apt a word choice.

Comment: Point being: not all examples are good examples.  It's good to be able to understand what the author meant, but that's not a great usage to emulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make use of some of the XP principles in defining other methodologies.

[See Merriam-Webster 1b](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cannibalize)